# Loop through hiding all divs but one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide several DIVs when a button is selected leaving only the one selected open. At the moment I am doing this using several onclick functions. Is there an easier, quicker and cleaner way than this?

So currently I have say 4 divs on displayed and closed like this:

```js
function selectcheck() {
    $('#show2').hide();
    $('#show3').hide();
    $('#show4').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show1"> Content here with a <button type='button' id='button1' name='button1' onclick='selectcheck()' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div id="show2"> Content here with a <button type='button' id='button2' name='button2' onclick='selectcheck2()' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div id="show3"> Content here with a <button type='button' id='button3' name='button3' onclick='selectcheck3()' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div id="show4"> Content here with a <button type='button' id='button4' name='button4' onclick='selectcheck4()' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>
```

and the others the same. They all start with `show(number)`. Is there a way of looping through all hiding all but the one selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to note:

- Stay away from inline functions (ie. `selectcheck()`). You should use jQuery's bind function `$('button').on()` to attach a click function to each.
- From there, we can get all divs. You can assign them a classname if you have multiple divs outside this group. ie `$('div.content_hideable')` or `$('#content > div')`.
- When the button gets clicked, it passes the button to the function in the form of `this`. You can use jQuery's [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function to filter all the divs you want to hide, except the one that contains this button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('div').not($(this).parent()).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show1">1 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button1' name='button1' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div id="show2">2 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button2' name='button2' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div id="show3">3 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button3' name='button3' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div id="show4">4 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button4' name='button4' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>
```

To clarify your questions below, try something like the following to prevent clashes with other elements:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.show button').on('click', function() {
    $('div.show').not($(this).parent()).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show">1 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button1' name='button1' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div class="show">2 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button2' name='button2' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div class="show">3 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button3' name='button3' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>

<div class="show">4 Content here with a <button type='button' id='button4' name='button4' class='btn btn-select'>SELECT THIS</button></div>
```

Comment: Thats great it works but it closes everything including the one clicked!!

Comment: @wayneuk2 Hit run code snippet, and try it for yourself. It should be working correctly.

Comment: Its works on here but when I put that code on my page and click the button everything on the page disappears?

Comment: Yes, because you can't simply use `$('div')` as I've mentioned in the top half of the answer. You should either wrap them in a parent like: `<div id="content">` and use `$('#content > div')`, and/or assign each of them a class, like `<div class="can_hide">Content button</div>`, and use `$('.can_hide')`. I'd take a look into jQuery selectors when you get some time: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Confused? So if I want to close all the divs that start with 'show' how do I do it? Put them in a class?

Comment: @wayneuk2 Do you understand that when you type `$('div')` it matches every div on the page? In this case, it works in my example, because there are only 4 divs on that page. In your case, you may have hundreds, so you need to isolate and find only the elements you care about. You can do this several ways. Most common: Wrap the elements in a parent, and select the parent's children. `<div id="content><div></div><div></div></div>` => `$('div#content > div')`. Selects the direct descendants of `div#content`, other div's wont be selected.

Comment: Or, you can select them like my second example (I've updated my answer). Just assign them a class: `<div class="show"></div><div class="show"></div><div class="whatever"></div><div></div>` => `$('div.show').length is 2`

Comment: Well with added class it now does totally nothing!! Gonna give up and do it the way I was, when the button is clicked, nothing happens

Comment: what chat? Never used chat on here before?

Comment: Many thanks for your help Franker much appreciated, have it working like a charm and got a better understanding of how it all works, thanks